# Should i save all images to a file server and also on the Cloud?

Tags: image

I have a website, where the users can add photo albums and photos . I recently started using a startup Image Webservice company and use their apis to store the user images in their Cloud.

I am slightly concerned that what if the company goes out of business(there are so many new Cloud companies out there) and i loose all the images that the users uploaded ? So i was also saving the image files to the file server as well as saving on their Cloud.
I have  a folder in Webserver called Images, and when the user uploads the image file,  i create a  folder inside the Images folder based on userid and saves the file there.

My logic is if ever that company goes out of business, i can always retrieve the images from the webserver !

Is this the right thing to do ? Or am i getting too paranoid ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a cloud service when you're also saving the images to your own server?

If I was you, then I'd simply store all images on my own server and not rely on any other company.

Still the safest way, if you're paranoid about using a third-party site.

Comment: I was hoping  rendering from the cloud/CDN was faster than from a file server.

Comment: @user636525 That does really depend on your server - After all, I'd say that rendering from your own server is always the more secure way to go, as you have full control of everything and your website will still work when the cloud goes down for maintenance or stuff like that.